# How I can reduce number of queries in table in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am displaying 100 rows in laravel. In every row, I need to take the sum of a specific columns for each row.

That is what currently I am doing

```
@foreach($deals as $deal)
  <tr>
     <td>getNumberOfTrucksByLogisticsID($deal->truck_assigner_id, $user->owner_id, $isToday)</td>
  </tr>
  
@endforeach
```

This function  `getNumberOfTrucksByLogisticsID()` is having query

```
function getNumberOfTrucksByLogisticsID($assignerId, $owner_id, $isToday = false)
{
    if ($isToday) {
        $date_for_filter = Carbon::today();
    } else {
        $date_for_filter = getTommorrowDate();
    }
    $trucks_count = Deal::where('packaging_company_id', $owner_id)
        ->where('truck_assigner_id', $assignerId)
        ->whereDate('date_of_work', $date_for_filter)
        ->sum('no_of_trucks');

    if ($trucks_count == 0) {
        return '';
    }
    return '(' . $trucks_count . ' ocp) ';
}
```

Problem is there is one more function like that which is doing same thing. It becomes almost 200 queries. Which is not best practice My question is is there any way I can reduce these queries?

Comment: You might want to considering [caching](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache) your results. Also, if you have two functions that do the same thing, consider consolidating them into a single function.

Comment: Cache is good option . I tried it but it creates a lot of other issue like when updates it dont get update when it is deleted nothing get deleted

Comment: Not getting the most recent dataset is the trade-off of caching results to reduce database queries. You can adjust the storage time on the item you store in the cache to invalidate it. Deciding on what that time should be is a balance.

Comment: Its an immediate red flag whenever you have a database query inside a loop. You should a) do this in the controller, b) consider relationships so that you can eager load all deals per assigner.

Comment: For this case you could use collections, so all the data is in memory and you can perform queries similar to database to filter the data you need. this way would be way faster and efficient. If you need to use relationships try instead eager loading https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score -1):

you can pass limit option as parameter in function and use here

```
    function getNumberOfTrucksByLogisticsID($assignerId, $owner_id, $isToday = false, $limit = 10)
    {
     
     $date_for_filter = $isToday ? Carbon::today() : getTommorrowDate();
   
    $trucks_count = Deal::where('packaging_company_id', $owner_id)
    ->where('truck_assigner_id', $assignerId)
    ->whereDate('date_of_work', $date_for_filter)
    ->limit($limit)
    ->sum('no_of_trucks');

    return $trucks_count == 0 ? '' : '(' . $trucks_count . ' ocp) ';
    }
```